# why List.contain is returning false

Tags: java, arrays

please see the code below.

```
int[] intArray={1,2,3,4,3,4,5};
    List intList=Arrays.asList(intArray);
    System.out.println(intList.contains(1));
```

Above code is returning false.can any one pls explain why it is so?

Comment: You should never use raw types like `List`. If you had written `List<Integer>`, you'd have noticed that the code wouldn't compile anymore. Because `Arrays.asList` with a primitive integer array will return just a List with a single element, the array; not a list made of all the elements of the array.

Comment: Why the -2? For someone coming from say C++, this is not at all obvious. And the question text contains all that is necessary for an answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks sir,After seeing -2 I thought I asked the wrong question,i am novice to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` converts your primitive array to a `List<int[]>` whose single element is the array, `intList.contains(intArray)` would return `true`, but `intList.contains(1)` won't.

If you change your `int[]` array to `Integer[]`, you'll get your expected output - i.e. a `List<Integer>` that contains the elements of the original array.

Comment: thanks for the explanation